# Deleting Aliases unchecks 'generate automatic alias'

Tags: path-aliases

I'm sure this is a bug.

I have a bunch of alias paths set where page URLs are generated based on menu location. I'm testing to see if I restructure the site and move a lot of content around, can I use path-auto, bulk update to change all the URLs.

Obviously I can't update without deleting the existing ones first (tested).

So I went in and delete all the aliases via Admin > Config > Search > URL aliases > Delete aliases. All aliases deleted, great.

But Bulk update won't give me new aliases. After a bit of poking around it turns out that running Delete Aliases has caused the 'Generate Automatic Alias" checkbox to be turned OFF on all my content.

so...

1. Why did running Delete Aliases cause all my content to change to using custom aliases?
2. Can I (somehow) revert all pages to automatic aliases?

Note - I'm using the [govCMS distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/govcms), so adding modules like VBO is not an option. I have almost zero understanding of drush, but I'm willing to dive in with instructions.

Note again - I had pathauto persistant state enabled when this happened.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, never mind. I spent over an hour with this repeatedly happening, dug through pages full of people having the same issue and the opposite issue, flicked persistant state on and off, and it suddenly started working in the time it took me to write this. Caching I guess